# Python Django: join view on the admin interface

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

I have a model for universities and another for contacts:

```
class University(models.Model):

    abbrev = models.CharField(max_length=20, unique=True) # example "ASU" for Alabama State University
    name = models.CharField(max_length=512, unique=True)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=512)
    state = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=STATE_CHOICES) # abbreviation
    region = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=REGION_CHOICES) # examples Mid West, South Coast, etc.
    type = models.CharField(max_length=3, choices=TIPO_IES_CHOICES) # public, private, etc.

class UniversityContact(models.Model):

    person ...
    university ... # models.OneToOneField("University") ???
```

When editing UniversityContact on the admin interface, I would like to be able to "pull" `'abbrev', 'state', 'region',` and `'type'` from University to show together with the contact info. Is that possible? They don't have to be editable from that context.

I've tried adding those fields to UniversityContact, all as "`models.OneToOneField("University", related_name='...')`", but they all end up showing the same value - `abbrev` - from the other table.

I'd like to be able to quickly sort contacts by, say, region, etc.

Comment: Arizona State, Damn it! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Displaying is easy - define a method that returns the related data on the model or the admin class, then use the method in `list_display` and/or `readonly_fields`.

For sorting, define the `admin_order_field` property of the method. Although `list_display` and `readonly_fields` do not support the double underscore related field syntax, `admin_order_field` does. So something like this:

```
class UniversityContact(models.Model):
    # as above, plus:
    def abbrev(self):
        return self.university.abbrev
    abbrev.admin_order_field = 'university__abbrev'
```

Optionally you can set the `short_description` attribute as well, if you don't want the default choic of the method name:

```
    abbrev.short_description = 'abbreviation'
```

You didn't ask about this, but it seems worth knowing - `list_filter` also supports the standard related field name syntax:

```
    list_filter = ('university__region',)
```

Alternatively, there's a code snippet here that claims to address it:
http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/2887/

I haven't tested that myself.

Comment: Thank you! Your last comment regarding the standard related field syntax within `list_filter` actually made it! I did not know I could have the filters like that by just connecting one of the columns from each table.

Comment: That was added in version 1.3 if I recall correctly. Personally I'm a bit surprised that it's not supported in `list_display` and `readonly_fields`; one discussion on the mailing list blames that on the difficulty of figuring out the name for the related field, but the list filter use has to tackle that problem too. I'm probably overlooking some complexity, since the people who discussed it and judged it unfeasible are core devs and not likely to have overlooked something obvious. https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/django-developers/eQSEv74bQh8